# Conditional probabilities problem

Tags: probability

I need help on the last step of a problem I am trying to solve:

$X, Y$ are integrable r.v. and I proved that $$\mathbb{P}((X-Y)(1_{X \geq c}-1_{Y \geq c})=0)=1$$ for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$

I need to prove that $X=Y$ a.s.

I was thinking of doing it by using the law of total probability and conditioning on the two events $\{X=Y\}$ and $\{X\not = Y\}$

So that $$1=\mathbb{P}((X-Y)(1_{X \geq c}-1_{Y \geq c})=0)=\mathbb{P}(X=Y) + \mathbb{P}(X\not = Y)\mathbb{P}((1_{X \geq c}-1_{Y \geq c})=0 \ | X\not = Y ) $$

Which then should lead to $\mathbb{P}(X\not = Y)=0$ by arbitrarieness of $c$

Am I completely out of track?

Thanks

Comment: Your method seems sane, you're on the right track. I can't give very specific advice since I've not got any more information on $X$ or $Y$. You'll most likely get your result by showing that if $X \geqslant c$ and $X \neq Y$ then $Y<c$ a.s., or a similar result with $X$ and $Y$ swapped round.

Comment: @ymbirtt the fact is that I know very little of $X$ and $Y$
I was thinking that I can choose $c$, while the equation would give me that the last probability should be constant (in $c$)

Comment: Ah, that makes things more interesting. If you assume that $\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \neq 1$, then a bit of tinkering reduces the statement to $\mathbb{P}(1_{X \geqslant c} - 1_{Y \geqslant c} | X \neq Y) = 1$. Now, if we know that this holds for every fixed value of $c$, we could possibly integrate across all values of $X$ and $Y$ using a _variable_ $c$ that's always between $X$ and $Y$, but I'm not sure if you're allowed to make that leap here - replacing a fixed term in an integral with a variable one is probably not very allowed.

Comment: Actually, wait, no, I think that's fine, let's do this.

Comment: @ymbirtt I see what you mean, not really convinced it is fine though. I am probably missing something from an earlier stage...

Comment: Hey, you might be able to get away with a countable dense set of such $c$'s, and note that the union of a countable union of  zero-proability sets is still zero-probability.

Comment: @Evan I don't really get what you mean, I could get that the union over all the rational $c$ 's of such events is zero.
How would that imply the fact that $X\not = Y$ a.s. though?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \neq 0$.

I am given that, $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$
\mathbb{P}(X = Y) + \mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \mathbb{P}(1_{X \geqslant c} - 1_{Y \geqslant c} = 0 | X \neq Y) = 1
$$

Which suggests that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} (X \neq Y) &= \mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \mathbb{P}(1_{X \geqslant c} - 1_{Y \geqslant c} = 0 | X \neq Y)\\
1 &=\mathbb{P}(1_{X \geqslant c} - 1_{Y \geqslant c} = 0 | X \neq Y)
\end{align}

This holds for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $c = \frac{X+Y}{2}$, so regardless of the values realised by $X$ and $Y$, either $X < c < Y$ or $Y < c < X$.

So $1_{X \geqslant c} - 1_{Y \geqslant c} \neq 0$ a.s.

This leads to a contradiction, so it must be the case that $\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) = 0$, and $X = Y$ a.s.

Comment: This way you are taking $c$ a random variable!

I am not entirely convinced...

Comment: Hm. Yeah, after my initial response of "it's probably fine", it's now looking less fine. I'm wondering if we can argue that, since the statement holds for every real $c$, it will also hold for a random $c$, but I'm still debating this with myself now. I'm looking forward to seeing how this actually does pan out, once your teacher gives you the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Building off ymbirtt answer,  take the intersection of countably many events so that given that $X\neq Y$, almost surely we have that **for all rational** $c$ either both $X,Y$ are less than $c$ or both greater than $c$. Such an event is impossible by density of rationals if $X$ and $Y$ are different, so it is a contradiction and the the event that $X\neq Y$ happens with probability zero.